# Pegar registro no banco e se duplicado, mostrar somente um

Tags: mysql

tenho uma tabela no banco chamada pedidos, onde o número do controle pode ser duplicado, pois o cliente no mesmo pedido pode comprar 2 itens, ou seja, cada linha vai inserir um produto comprado mas com o mesmo numero de controle, e eu queria que na hora de exibir os produtos comprados, mostrar apenas um, e ai quando eu clicar eu vou mostrar o resto, porém na exibição eu preciso que ele me traga apenas 1, pode ser o ultimo registro desse controle, e não duplicado como está vindo. não sei se fui claro.

```
<table class="table">
                                                <thead>
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <th scope="col">Número pedido</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Data</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Valor</th>
                                                    <th scope="col">Situação</th>
                                                  </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                        <?
                                            $result = ("SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE id_cliente = '".$usr_id."' ORDER BY id DESC");
                                            $execute = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

                                            if(mysqli_num_rows ($execute) > 0 )
                                            {
                                                while ($dados_cliente = mysqli_fetch_assoc($execute)){
                                                $data = $dados_cliente['data'];
                                                $controle = $dados_cliente['identificacao_pedido'];
                                                $valor_pedido = $dados_cliente['valor_pedido'];
                                                $valor_frete = $dados_cliente['valor_frete'];
                                                $situacao = $dados_cliente['situacao'];

                                              $total = $valor_pedido+$valor_frete;
                                              if ($situacao=='ag') {
                                                $exibir_situacao = 'Aguardando Pagamento';
                                              }
                                              elseif ($situacao=='ap') {
                                                $exibir_situacao = 'Pagamento Aprovado';
                                              }
                                              elseif ($situacao=='cn') {
                                                $exibir_situacao = 'Pagamento Cancelado';
                                              }
                                              elseif ($situacao=='sp') {
                                                $exibir_situacao = 'Em separação';
                                              }
                                              elseif ($situacao=='tr') {
                                                $exibir_situacao = 'Em transporte';
                                              }
                                              elseif ($situacao=='en') {
                                                $exibir_situacao = 'Pedido Entregue';
                                              }
                                            ?>

                                                <tbody>
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <th scope="row">#<?=$controle;?></th>
                                                    <td><?=$data;?></td>
                                                    <td>R$ <?=number_format($total,2,',','.');?></td>
                                                    <td><span><strong><?=$exibir_situacao;?></strong></span></td>
                                                  </tr>

                                                </tbody>


                                    <?}}else{?>
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
                                      <center>Você não efetuou nenhum pedido ainda.</center>
                                    </table>
                                    <?}?>
                                    </table>
```

Comment: Não poderia fazer uma consulta usando `DISTINCT` para listar apenas os valores, sem as repetições, e então ir para um outro elemento/página que mostra todos os itens independente de repetições?

Answer (score 0):

Opa!

Faz um distinct na sua query como o exemplo abaixo, assim você só vai exibir um de cada vez, e coloca um link de detalhes em cada linha para exibir todos as linhas.

```html
SELECT DISTINCT(CampoControle) FROM pedidos WHERE id_cliente = '".$usr_id."' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: então, funcionou, mas agora ele só ta exibindo campo controle e os valores e todo o resto nao ta mostrando

Comment: Coloca o restante dos campos no início da query após o select `SELECT DISTINCT(CampoControle), ColunaB, ColunaC FROM pedidos...`